# How to create a label based on unique combinations of rows of a matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, label, combinations

I have a matrix with 3 columns: the first column contains the `Year`, the second column contains the name of `Country 1` and the third column contains the name of `Country 2`. For example,

```
> mat <- cbind(c(1900,1900,1900,1901,1901,1901),  
+              c("USA","USA","FRANCE","USA","USA", "FRANCE") ,  
+              c("FRANCE", "GERMANY", "GERMANY","FRANCE", "GERMANY", "GERMANY") )
> mat
     [,1]   [,2]     [,3]     
[1,] "1900" "USA"    "FRANCE" 
[2,] "1900" "USA"    "GERMANY"
[3,] "1900" "FRANCE" "GERMANY"
[4,] "1901" "USA"    "FRANCE" 
[5,] "1901" "USA"    "GERMANY"
[6,] "1901" "FRANCE" "GERMANY"
```

I want to create a label for each combination. For instance, I would like to get, a vector `label =  c(1,2,3,1,2,3)`, indicating the different combinations. I know how to do it by brute force. This is, creating a list of unique combinations of country names with a package and then comparing each of these combinations with each row of `mat` and creating the vector `label` in a loop using the command `identical()`.

```
library(RcppAlgos)
cs <- as.character(unique(c(mat[,2],mat[,3])))
combos <- comboGeneral(cs, 2 , FALSE)
```

However, my matrix has 1000,000 rows and a couple of thousand combinations of country names, making this process really slow.

**QUESTION**: Is there a more efficient way of creating the `label` vector indicating the unique combinations of the second and third rows of the matrix `mat`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use match in base R:

```
mat <- cbind(c(1900,1900,1900,1901,1901,1901),  
                         c("USA","USA","FRANCE","USA","USA", "FRANCE") ,  
                         c("FRANCE", "GERMANY", "GERMANY","FRANCE", "GERMANY", "GERMANY") )


mat <- cbind(mat, paste(mat[,2], mat[,3]))
match(mat[,4], unique(mat[,4]))
```

Comment: Execution time: 1 second with your suggestion vs 1 day with brute force. The loop + comparison were very slow.

Comment: Great ! It is indeed way better.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit confused as to the output, though if it is as per the output of your given code; try the following:

```
library(dplyr)

mat <- cbind(c(1900,1900,1900,1901,1901,1901),c("USA","USA","FRANCE","USA","USA", "FRANCE") ,  
c("FRANCE", "GERMANY", "GERMANY","FRANCE", "GERMANY", "GERMANY") )

mat1 = as_data_frame(mat) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(labelCol = paste0(V2," ",V3))

allLabels = unique(mat1$labelCol)
```

Let me know if it works.